# ASM I/O pins HCS12 micro controller

Tags: c++, c, assembly, microcontroller

Iam using the HCS12 micro controller.  The following program that I have takes the input from an on board keypad and displays letters to an on board LCD depending on which key is pressed (I only attached the portion of the code dealing with the inputs / outputs, i can attach the rest if need be but its easier on the eyes this way).

What I would like to do is to get rid of the keypad being used as the inputs, and use a sensor that I have which sends active low signals though 3 separate pins instead.  That way in stead of having to push the keypad each time, whenever the sensor reads one of the readings (either PortA1, 2 or 3) it will display the correct letter.

The init_keypad function sets PortA0-PortA3 as inputs.

In the getkey function im not sure how to change the if statements to read PortA0-PortA3 individualy

```
void init_keypad(void){
    DDRA = 0xf0;  // PA7-PA4 output; PA3-PA0 input
    DDRB = 0xf0;
    PUCR |= 1;   // PUPAE =1 (enable pull-up on all PORTA inputs) 
}

char getkey(void){
    PORTA = 0xe0;       // selects row 0     
    if ((PORTA & 1) == 0){
    cmdwrt(0x01);
      delay(20);
      if ((PORTA & 1) == 0) return('L');//true if '1' key still active after 20 ms
    }
    PORTA = 0xd0;
    if ((PORTA & 1) == 0){
    cmdwrt(0x01);
      delay(20);
      if ((PORTA & 1) == 0) return('S');//true if '1' key still active after 20 ms
    }
    PORTA = 0xb0;  
    if ((PORTA & 1) == 0){
    cmdwrt(0x01);
      delay(20);
      if ((PORTA & 1) == 0) return('R');//true if '1' key still active after 20 ms
    }
```

Comment: What's your question, anyway?

Comment: How do I check each port (A0-A3) individually?  That way I can change the if statement to check for the status of the ports rather than the keypad.

Comment: What's the problem with accessing individual ports?

Comment: Im not sure how to access them individually.

Comment: Are you saying your inputs show up as bits 0, 1 and 2 of PORTA?

Comment: Using the sensor it should show up as a low signal on pin 0, 1, 2 of portA.  How ever how I set an if statement to check each individual port pin is what I cant figure out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume you've read the input from PORTA into variable we'll name `input`.

In that case, testing the individual bits of `input` looks something like:

```
if (input & 1) { 
   // bit 0 was set
}
if (input & 2) {
   // bit 1 was set
}
if (input & 4) {
   // bit 2 was set
}
```

Comment: Why do you AND with 2 and 4?

Comment: Because 2 is `00000010` in binary and 4 is `00000100` in binary, so anding with them isolates the second and third bits respectively.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using something like CodeWarrior IDE to do your HCS12 programming, you'll notice a header file being included in your HCS12 project. It will be the name of the chip you want to compile for, eg. `mc9s12c32.h`. Within that file, you can see definitions for the addresses, and contents of each register available to you. `PORTA` for example is defined as a variable which points to `0x0` in memory. To be able to read a specific pin on port A, the following can be used to help mitigate any confusion.

```
if(PORTA & PORTA_BIT0_MASK)
{
    //Do something if bit 0 was set
}
if(PORTA & PORTA_BIT1_MASK)
{
    //Do something if bit 1 was set
}
if(PORTA & PORTA_BIT2_MASK)
{
    //Do something if bit 2 was set
}
```

What is done above, is a test between the entire contents of port A, and whether or not each individual bit is set on that port. `PORTA_BIT0_MASK` happens to be defined as `1`, `PORTA_BIT1_MASK` as `2`, and `PORTA_BIT2_MASK` as `4`.